# CheckBox Node Tree

Tags: java, swing, jtree, jcheckbox

I have a checkbox node tree using java Swing. 
My objective is to select all the check box nodes on the click of a button .

i.e

Pseudo Code :

```
on(button click){    
    Check all the check box nodes 
}
```

Code :

```
for (CheckBoxNode node_r : checkBoxRows)
{
    node_r.setSelected(true);
    frame.repaint();
}
```

checkBoxRows is a list containing all the parent nodes in the check box node tree .

Can you guide me the correct way of doing this ?

Comment: For better help sooner, post an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`checkBoxRows is a list containing all the parent nodes`

1) no needed that, because [JTree](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/tree.html) implements own [TreeModel](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/tree.html#data), only if is there extra `Controler`, then you have to implements `Vector<Object>`, because `TreeModel` is TwoDimensional by default, and `List` has only one dimension

2) you can simle loops inside `TreeModel` with checking for `JCheckBox` and if returns `true/false` from method `isSelected`

3) examples for [JTree, TreeModel, JTree Renderer](http://www.java2s.com/Code/Java/Swing-JFC/CatalogSwing-JFC.htm)